# JS wont recognize a variable within angular controller object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to create a simple login verification, however the validation function seizes to function when the validation comparison begins, and the console sais that the variable **"userName is not defined"** although it clearly is.

Can enyone tell me what am i defining wrong?

the angular controller code:

```
var app = angular.module("LoginApp", []);
app.controller("LoginController", function ($http) {
    this.userName = "";
    this.password = "";
    this.userNameValid = true;
    this.passwordValid = true;

    /*submit the form*/
    this.submit = function () {
        alert("submit");
        this.validate();

    };

    /* make sure user name and password has been inserted*/
    this.validate = function () {
        alert("validate");
        var result = true;
        this.userNameValid = true;
        this.passwordValid = true;

        if (this.userName == "") {
            alert("username="+userName);
            this.userNameValid = false;
            result = false;
        }

        if (this.password == "") {
            this.passwordValid = false;
            result = false;
        }
        alert("validuserNameValid==" + userNameValid + " passwordValid==" + passwordValid);
        return result;
    };
});
```

the HTML form:

```
<body ng-app="LoginApp" ng-controller="LoginController as LoginController">

        <form role="form" novalidate name="loginForm" ng-submit="LoginController.submit()">
            <div id="loginDetails">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user"> User Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="user" class="form-control" ng-model="LoginController.userName" required />
                    <span ng-show="LoginController.userNameValid==false" class="alert-danger">field is requiered</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" >Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="LoginController.password" required />
                    <span ng-show="LoginController.passwordValid==false" class="alert-danger">field is requiered</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    {{"entered information:" +"\n"+LoginController.userName+" "+ LoginController.password}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

the log:

```
Error: userName is not defined

this.validate@http://localhost:39191/login.js:23:13
this.submit@http://localhost:39191/login.js:11:9
anonymous/fn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js line 231 > Function:2:292
b@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:126:19
Kc[b]</<.compile/</</e@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:274:195
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:103
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:335
Kc[b]</<.compile/</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:274:245
Rf@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:37:31
Qf/d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:36:486
```

Comment: Can u have a look at below alert statment, shouldnt it be a this.userName ????if (this.userName == "") {
            alert("username="+userName);
            this.userNameValid = false;
            result = false;
        }

Comment: that actually was part of it

Comment: You should look at "Satpal's" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `this` judiciously. I would recommend you to store the reference of `this` in variable then use it wherever required.

```
var app = angular.module("LoginApp", []);
app.controller("LoginController", function ($http) {
    //Store the reference of this in a variable
    var lc = this;

    //Use the stored refrence
    lc.userName = "";

    /* make sure user name and password has been inserted*/
    lc.validate = function () {
        if (lc.userName == "") {
            alert("username="+userName);
            lc.userNameValid = false;
            result = false;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, by setting the context of the controller to a variable and then referencing the variable through out the controller.

Answer (score 0):

inside your alert boxes you have not mentioned this.userName try removing the alert boxes or change them.